# validation function problem

Tags: java

Hello 
I am not able to get the correct validation.I think there is some error in this code so can anyone please help me solving this problem.

```
 public static boolean validateFee(String value) {

        boolean isvalid = true;
        try {
            int fee = 0;
            if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
                fee = Integer.parseInt(value);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            // ne.printStackTrace();
            isvalid = false;
            return isvalid;

        }
        return isvalid;
    }
}
```

I am actaully using this code for validation of fee in which i m using a regex as [0-9]+.
This code i m using it in a common function.Actually validation call is done in the servlet as follows:

```
private Boolean validateFee(HttpSession session, PropertiesHandler props, String number) {
    Boolean isvalid = true;
    HashMap hashMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    number = ApplicationConstants.FEE_PATTERN;
    if (!Validation.validateFee(number)) {
        isvalid = false;
        hashMap.put("time", props.getText("error.fee.invalid.type"));
    }
    session.setAttribute("errorMessage", hashMap);
    System.out.println("Map size " + hashMap.size());
    logger.info("Exit validateTIme"); return isvalid;
}
```

I think there is no error in that but i have a doubt in this function.I am facing a problem like if i give number to the fee also its taking validation.please help me out

Comment: Do you have any inputs for which this fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it allows value of null or "" to count as being valid - is that deliberate?

Note that your current code can be rewritten more simply:

```
public static boolean validateFee(String value) {
    try {
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
            Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now if you want null/empty to count as invalid, I'd rewrite it as:

```
public static boolean validateFee(String value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(value);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i used this code but still i m not able to get the answer.The code below is my validation for fee function.

Comment: I m getting fee unused when i use my program

Comment: @yopirates: *What* answer? You still haven't said what's actually wrong. If you could give an example where it's giving the wrong answer, that would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Well my code doesn't even *have* a `fee` variable, so it wouldn't give that error/warning...

Comment: The problem is that i m not able to validate for fee.If i give numeric values then it should take or else it should show an error message.But my code is giving error message to numeric values also.

Comment: private Boolean validateFee(HttpSession session, PropertiesHandler props, String number) {
        
        Boolean isvalid = true;
        HashMap hashMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        
        number = ApplicationConstants.FEE_PATTERN;
        if (!Validation.validateFee(number)) {
            isvalid = false;
            hashMap.put("time", props.getText("error.fee.invalid.type"));

        }

        session.setAttribute("errorMessage", hashMap);
        System.out.println("Map size " + hashMap.size());
        logger.info("Exit validateTIme");
        return isvalid;
    }

Comment: @Jon , I think we shouldn't relay on exception for decision making. what do you say. Thanks btw.

Comment: here ApplicationConstants.FEE_PATTERN=[0-9]+ which i have given in applicationconstants.java

Comment: @or.life.java yes need to relay on exception to validate

Comment: The problem in your code is that you are validating the pattern not the actual value, `[0-9]+` is not a valid integer.

Comment: cant i use a regex pattern to validate this.I m actually new to this so.

Comment: import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.StringUtils;

Comment: @org.life.java: Typically, no. But this is very localized, and *may* be the best way of approaching it. (I don't think Java has anything like .NET's int.TryParse, unfortunately.) I'm still trying to work out exactly what the question is.

Comment: @yopirates: You're being *really* unclear about what you want. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints thoroughly. Note that a regex of just digits will match something like 999999999999999999999999999 which then can't be parsed as an int. Do you want that to be valid or not?

Comment: let me explain clearly.I want to validation doctor consultation fee in which it should not take alpabets as of now.It can take any number of numeric value.I don want to validate for that particulart pattern and i m not giving the range for that.I want that as a string in my validation.I m declaring my regex pattern as string

Answer (score 1):

trim your string and then pass it to.

```
StringUtils.isNumeric(StringUtils.trimToNull(fees));
```

You can directly use [StringUtils.isNumeric()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: That even matches the empty string.

Comment: `StringUtils.trimToNull(fees)` would be better

Comment: life.java, I don't get it, `StringUtils.isNumeric("".trim());` is still true

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use commons-lang [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) class, your validate method is re-written

```
public static boolean validateFee(String value) {
    return StringUtils.isNumeric(StringUtils.trimToNull(value));
}
```

And you remove `ApplicationConstants.FEE_PATTERN` completely.  The problem you are currently facing is that your servlet overwrites its input value with `ApplicationConstants.FEE_PATTERN`.  Your servlet method is re-written

```
private Boolean validateFee(HttpSession session, PropertiesHandler props, String number) {
    final Boolean valid = Validation.validateFee(number);
    if (!valid) {
        final HashMap hashMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        hashMap.put("time", props.getText("error.fee.invalid.type"));
        session.setAttribute("errorMessage", hashMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use commons-lang then use one of Jon Skeet's implementations, you still need to fix the bug in your servlet code.

Comment: what i should change in my servlet code if i use Jon Skeet's code?